# Reactjs: Uncaught TypeError: Object(...)(...).then is not a function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this project and in this project I have these two files, the first file is the form file, and the second file is the service file, and I want to access the answer contained within the service file, but I have this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...)(...).then is not a function
```

how can i solve it?

And this file contains a form, and through this form, I want to call the getjobs function

```
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Controller, useFormContext } from "react-hook-form";
import { getJobs } from "../../store/salaryScalesSlice";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Autocomplete } from "@material-ui/lab";

function ShippingTab(props) {
  const methods = useFormContext();
  const { control } = methods;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getJobs());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const [jobs, setJobs] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getJobs().then((response) => setJobs(response));
  }, []);

  console.log("jobs: ", jobs);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex -mx-4">
        <Controller
          name="job"
          control={control}
          defaultValue={[]}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
            <Autocomplete
              disablePortal
              id="combo-box-demo"
              style={{ width: 900 }}
              className="mt-8 mb-16"
              options={jobs || []}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name || ""}
              value={value}
              onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                onChange(newValue);
              }}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  placeholder="Select Job Name"
                  label="Job"
                  variant="outlined"
                  fullWidth
                  InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,
                  }}
                />
              )}
            />
          )}
        />
        <Controller
          name="employeeLevel"
          control={control}
          defaultValue={[]}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
            <Autocomplete
              id="employeeLevel"
              style={{ width: 900 }}
              className="mt-8 mb-16 mx-4"
              options={employeeLevels || []}
              getOptionLabel={(option) => option.employeeLevel || ""}
              value={value}
              onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                onChange(newValue);
              }}
              renderInput={(params) => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  placeholder="Select Employee Level"
                  label="Employee Level"
                  variant="outlined"
                  fullWidth
                  InputLabelProps={{
                    shrink: true,
                  }}
                />
              )}
            />
          )}
        />

        <Controller
          name="amount"
          control={control}
          render={({ field }) => (
            <TextField
              {...field}
              className="mt-8 mb-16"
              label="Amount"
              id="amount"
              variant="outlined"
              InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="start">$</InputAdornment>
                ),
              }}
              fullWidth
            />
          )}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ShippingTab;

const employeeLevels = [
  { employeeLevel: "senior" },
  { employeeLevel: "junior" },
  { employeeLevel: "mid_level" },
];
```

service.js:

```
export const getJobs = createAsyncThunk("jobsRequests/getJobs", async () => {
  const response = await axios.get("/jobs").then((res) => {
    const jobsRequestsData = res.data.data;
    console.log("jobsRequestsData: ", jobsRequestsData);
    return jobsRequestsData;
  });

  return response;
})
```

Comment: Why you `return response;` in `getJobs`? Remove it and should work.... Read [this](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-typeerror-then-is-not-a-function#:~:text=The%20%22then%20is%20not%20a,()%20method%20on%20valid%20promises.) to know why is wrong that return.

Comment: can u edit my post?, i read the article and i tried to solve the problem but it doesn't solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing promises and async/await toghether which leads to unexpected behaviour and therefore should be avoided.

The await keyword returns the response on which you cannot call .then()

If you want to stick with the async/await method change `getjobs` function to something as follows (not tested, just to give an idea)

```
const getJobs = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get("/jobs");
  return response.data.data;
}
```

otherwise you could remove the async/await keyowrds and return a promise.

---

The second problem is the `createAsyncThunk`.
The error you get is in the useEffect hook.

As the documentation says:

> The thunks generated by createAsyncThunk will always return a resolved
> promise

You should implement the full redux flow for setting the props. See [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) or remove it.

Comment: the error is still found

Comment: Hi @HibaYoussef, see the udpated answer. The second problem is the mixing of redux with other calls.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object(...)(...).then is not a function

Comment: problem still found

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to return twice, just remove the return response:

```
export const getJobs = createAsyncThunk("jobsRequests/getJobs", async () => {
  const response = await axios.get("/jobs").then((res) => {
    return res.data.data
  });

})
```

Comment: Hi @yanir, this example is still mixing async/await and promises

Comment: the problem still found